# FreshMvvm - PopPageModel not works on Android

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, freshmvvm

I have a Xamarin.Forms app and I am using FreshMvvm framework.

If I do this from ViewIsAppearing method of FirstPageModel:

```
CoreMethods.PushPageModel<SecondPageModel>();
```

I go the "SecondPageModel". Then, when I am in the "SecondPageModel" if I do:

```
CoreMethods.PopPageModel();
```

or press hard back button, or press title bar back button not works in Android (anything happens). I am using FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer.

In iOS it works OK, I get back to FirstPageModel.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code I have a feeling you are doing it from a background thread!

Comment: The PushPageModel<SecondPageModel> is done in the UI thread, because it shows the SecondPageModel correctly. But in this, when I press hard back button, it always is called in the UI thread, not works. I think there isn't a thread problem. However, I try Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {              CoreMethods.PopPageModel();  }); and still not works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `ViewIsAppearing` will always be called when the page starts displaying on the screen. When you pop the second page then go to the first page, the first page's `ViewIsAppearing` will fire again. It caused a dead cycle and prohibited your app from returning to the first page.

Add a property to avoid that:

```
bool isInitialized;
public FirstPageModel()
{
    // ...

    isInitialized = true;
}

protected async override void ViewIsAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.ViewIsAppearing(sender, e);

    if (isInitialized)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        await CoreMethods.PushPageModel<SecondPageModel>();
        isInitialized = false;
    }

}
```

iOS may optimize this process, but I still recommend you to add this judgment statement.

**Update:**

Call it when your app has reached the main thread.

```
protected override void ViewIsAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.ViewIsAppearing(sender, e);

    if (isInitialized)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            CoreMethods.PushPageModel<SecondPageModel>();
            isInitialized = false;
        });
    }           
}
```

Comment: It works! But if I delete the Task.Delay(100); line not works. Can you explain me why need to delay the PushPageModel? Thanks!

Comment: @Josecanalla This is because `ViewIsAppearing` may be still in a thread. You could try the approach in my update.

Comment: Yes, it works with updated answer! Thank you. Sorry for my late answer.